# CSS style object of JSX in loop is changing into {[Object]} - React Native (Android Device)

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native, jsx

I'm creating JSX through loop and assigning it to the variable

Here is the JSX

```
const viewItems = [];
    viewItems.push(
        <View style={styles.documentView}>
            <Text style={styles.documentText} onPress={() => Linking.openURL("abc")}>
                xyz
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
```

Here is the css

```
documentView: { flex: 1, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom:10, alignItems: 'flex-start'},
documentText: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 18}
```

Now when i'm printing the viewItems variable by console.log(viewItems) I got the following result, where Parent View that has styles.documentView css is printing fine but the child element Text css is turning into {[object]}

```
<View style={{"alignItems": "flex-start", "flex": 1, "flexDirection": "row", "marginBottom": 10, "width": "100%"}}>
    <Text onPress={[Function onPress]} style={[Object]}>xyz</Text>
</View>
```

I tried JSON.stringify(styles.documentText) and it printed this

```
<View style={{"alignItems": "flex-start", "flex": 1, "flexDirection": "row", "marginBottom": 10, "width": "100%"}}>
    <Text onPress={[Function onPress]} style="{\"color\":\"blue\",\"fontSize\":18}">xyz</Text>
</View>
```

**UPDATE:**

I found pushing into array is creating the issue. When I tried to print the object before adding it to the array it prints well. Following is the code:

```
const view = (
    <View style={styles.documentView}>
        <Text style={styles.documentText} onPress={() => Linking.openURL("abc")}>xyz</Text>
    </View>
);
console.log(view) //printing fine
viewItems.push(view);
console.log(viewItems) //printing child element style string as Object
```

Wondering what makes pushing items to the array is creating the issue.

Comment: There is no problem with your code, that is just the string representation when printing. Is it rendering the components on the view correctly? Is there a reason why you would want to `console.log` jsx?

Comment: console.log is just to show the actual problem. Issue is, it is not rendering the view when it has object in style. Screen turns blank.

Comment: Also string representation of parent element is fine. Issue is with child elements only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Issue was with (flex: 1) property in main view.

```
<View style={{"alignItems": "flex-start", "flex": 1, "flexDirection": "row", "marginBottom": 10, "width": "100%"}}> <View>
```

After I changed flex: 1 with display: 'flex', it rendered the data.

```
<View style={{"alignItems": "flex-start", display: "flex", "flexDirection": "row", "marginBottom": 10, "width": "100%"}}> <View>
```